# Get pixel size of a NSBitmapImageRep?

Tags: cocoa

What is the best way to get the size (width and height) of an NSBitmapImageRep?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap;

NSInteger samplesPerPixel = [bitmap samplesPerPixel];
NSInteger bytesPerPlane = [bitmap bytesPerPlane];
NSInteger bytesPerRow = [bitmap bytesPerRow];
NSInteger numberOfPlanes = [bitmap numberOfPlanes];

NSUInteger numPixels = numberOfPlanes * bytesPerPlane / samplesPerPixel;
NSUInteger width = bytesPerRow / samplesPerPixel;
NSUInteger height = numPixels / width;
```

Seems like an awful lot of typing for something that should be as easy as [bitmap getWidth]...

I've seen some posts on the internet that query the size like this (this is not in the documentation):

```
NSSize imageSize = [bitmap size];
```

But the values don't seem to represent the pixel dimensions of the image (for example, I get a float value of 122.869835 instead of 256, which is the real pixel width of the image).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [`[rep pixelsWide]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImageRep/pixelsWide)
- [`[rep pixelsHigh]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImageRep/pixelsHigh)

Comment: @peter: where did you find this information? I looked and it's not in the documentation of NSBitmapImageRep.

Comment: Click on the links, and you'll see that these methods are (and their documentation is) in NSBitmapImageRep's superclass, NSImageRep.